# Scanning CANBUS

Tags: obd-ii, can-bus, electronic-control-module

I am in search for a method of scanning the CAN on my car using a cheap ELM327 chip.

I can query the ECU (made by Denso) without issue, however when I attempt to set the ELM327 scanner into promiscuous mode (via ATMA), I am not presented with any information back - that is, I am required to send commands to get a response.

I have confirmed with a dealer that many things in my car can be queried, using their dealer level scan tool (A DS-II made by Denso, which is very similar to the Toyota Intelligent Tester), such as unlocking the boot / trunk by plugging in their dealer level scan tool to the OBD-II port and talking to the boot's computer.

What I am wondering is, where do I start? Is there a software package for Windows / Linux / OSX that I can? What about hardware (Will my ELM 327 OBD-II device work)?

Answer (score 1):

The CAN-bus in its simple form is two wires that a series of microprocessors connect on too. There is not a processor to read or write to for 'CAN'. As the dealer has illustrated, you talk to the boots processor(*body processor*) to activate or de-activate the features of the processor. CAN - two wires, hi and lo, with a 120 ohm resistor joining them together at each end, allows you to connect to the various processors on the vehicle through the DLC plug.